# "Усвояемый" или "усваиваемый"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить "усвояемый", а не "усваиваемый"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно *усвояемый* и правильно. Во всяком случае это историческая форма. *Усваиваемый* - более новая и до недавнего времени не считалась нормативной ни на каком уровне. Сейчас некоторые словари признают её разговорной, но не более.

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, что если речь идёт о причастии действительного залога от глагола «усваивать», то по всем правилам русского языка это должно быть слово «усваиваемый». Ну, а коль скоро должно, то так и есть. Тогда откуда же взялось слово «усвояемый» и почему оно находит такую мощную поддержку в виде множества словарей? Всё дело в том, что глагол «усваивать» – относительно молодой, ещё лет сто назад он звучал как «усвоивать», а до того и вовсе – «усвоять». Это-то и объясняет происхождение нашего слова.

Comment: Интересная версия (в отношении "усвовать" и "усвоять"), но в силу своей новации совершенно не проходящая без ссылок на информацию из авторитетных источников. Кто-нибудь фиксировал такое употребление?  "Усвоять" встречается (редко) в значениях "присвоить" и "освоить" начиная с середины XIX века, а "усваивать" в те же времена была вполне употребима. Правда, у неё было другое управление: "усваивать что"  и "усваивать кому".

Comment: И еще. О каких "всех правилах русского языка" вы говорите? Да еще употребляя столь императивное "очевидно"?

Answer (score 4):

)Если вспомнить, что причастия в русском языке образуются с помощью нескольких формообразующих суффиксов, то в слове Усваиваемый очень легко обнаружить один из этих суффиксов - ЕМ, а само слово тогда образовано от инфинитива Усваивать. В его составе мы видим тот же корень -СВА-, суффикс ИВА, который достался причастию по наследству от инфинитива и суффикс причастия -ЕМ.
То есть слово Усваиваемый написано совершенно правильно, хотя и произнести его не всем получится с первого раза.
По этому же принципу мы можем выделить суффикс ЕМ и в слове Усвояемый, и посмотреть его морфемный состав. Корень -СВА- сохраняется, добавляется суффикс глагола Я, который должен соответствовать суффиксу инфинитива. И получается глагол Усвоять. Этот глагол в словарях идет с пометкой "устаревший", но тем не менее он реальный. Так что и причастие Усвояемый также верно написано.
Значение этих глаголов и причастий идентично, так что они могут заменять друг друга. Хотя сейчас мало кто поймет слово Усвоять.

Answer (score 0):

**Из словаря**

**УСВОИТЬ,** усвою, усвоишь; **усвояемый; усвояем**, св. что. 1. Сделать своим, присущим себе, привычным для себя что-л. новое, постороннее, чужое. У. дурную привычку. У. какую-л. манеру поведения.   страд. **Усваивание**, -я; ср. У. нового учебного материала. **Усвоение**, -я; ср. У. пищи.

1. Существует видовая пара глаголов:  ***усвоить*** и ***усваивать***. Страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются от глаголов **несовершенного вида**, то есть должно быть ***усваиваемый***, но во многих  словарях этой формы нет, хотя есть «усваивание».  Там обычно указывается причастие ***усвояемый***:  «Кролики – это не только ценный мех, но и два-три килограмма диетического **легкоусвояемого** мяса».
2. https://newslab.ru/article/180394

Статья: **Работа над ошибками: усвояемый или усваиваемый?**

«Почему? Всё дело в том, что глагол «***усваивать***» – относительно молодой, ещё лет сто назад он звучал как «***усвоивать***», а до того и вовсе – «***усвоять***». Это-то и объясняет происхождение нашего слова.

Итак,  «глагол устаревает, а образованное от него причастие сохраняет всю свою силу и по-прежнему находит место в лексиконе современного человека. Объяснение этому я вижу в большей дружественности старого слова к языку как инструменту общения. **Выговорить** «усвояемый» не в пример проще и быстрее, чем «усваиваемый».

Эксперты сайта spravka.gramota.ru полагают, что между этими словами существует **разница в значениях**. «***Усвояемый***», по их мнению, употребляется как **термин**, то есть в научном или официальном контексте, а слово «***усваиваемый***» – общеупотребительное, то есть чаще используется в обычной речи людей.

Как бы то ни было, ясно одно: слово «***усвояемый***» существовало, существует, и в его правильности не стоит сомневаться ни на йоту».