# Высокоусваеваемый или высокоусвояемый?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Почему везде "высокоусвояемый", когда правильно "высокоусваиваемый"?

Comment: усваивать - усвоять
усваивает - усвояет
усваиваю - усвояю
усвоили - усвояли
усваивал - усвайял)
но в интернете везде упорно усвОЯЕМЫЙ и пишут, что и в словарях тоже!

Answer (score 2):

В восьмидесятых годах прошлого столетия была чрезвычайно популярна постановка, снятая по миниатюре Владимира Перцова «Кролики — это не только ценный мех» (1986). Вы легко можете найти эту постановку в Интернете в вариантах от Моисеенко/Данильца и Панкратова-Черного/Брондукова.
Сюжет миниатюры строится вокруг приезда столичного журналиста к малограмотному председателю колхоза. Одним из ключевых моментов их диалога как раз и являлось произношение фразы:

> Кролики - это не только ценный мех, но и 3-4 килограмма диетического легкоусваиваемого мяса.

Председатель колхоза пытался говорить "усвояемого", а журналист объяснял ему, что правильно - "усваиваемого".
Там есть такой фрагмент:

```
- И запомните: усваиваемого. У-сва-ивае-мого.
- Простите, а это по-какому?
- Это ПО-ГРАМОТНОМУ!
```

С тех пор каждый волен для себя решать, на кого в своем произношении этого слова он хотел бы походить: на малограмотного председателя колхоза или на столичного журналиста.
Нисколько не хочу усомниться в мнении экспертов, но следует понимать, что с момента появления этой миниатюры общественное сознание воспринимает это именно так, а не иначе. И вы вряд ли будете после каждого использования слова "усвояемого" добавлять пространное объяснение, почем так правильнее. Вы просто скажете "усвояемого", а все вокруг вспомнят председателя колхоза.
Учитывайте это при принятии решения.

Answer (score 1):

**Усваиваемый** - находящийся в процессе усвоения.

**Усвояемый** - обладающий способностью быть усвоенным.

Способность быть усвоеннным может иметь *меру*, в отличие от "нахождения в процессе" - этот процесс либо имеет место, либо нет. Поэтому образовать слово, несущее в себе меру способности к усвоению, можно только от "усвояемый", отсюда правильно **высокоусвояемый**.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу статью Ежи Лисовского, с мнением которого я полностью согласен:

> [Работа над ошибками: усвояемый или усваиваемый?](http://newslab.ru/article/180394)
>   19.12.2005
>   «Кролики – это не только ценный мех, но и два-три килограмма диетического легкоусвояемого мяса». Как вы думаете, дорогие читатели, правильно ли написано выделенное слово? Не торопитесь дать ответ.
>
> Вопреки мнению нервного городского корреспондента из известного юмористического диалога, утверждающего, что слова «усвояемый» не существует, оно присутствует практически во всех словарях, в отличие от альтернативного «усваиваемый». Как же так? Очевидно, что если речь идёт о причастии действительного залога от глагола «усваивать», то по всем правилам русского языка это должно быть слово «усваиваемый». Ну, а коль скоро должно, то так и есть. Тогда откуда же взялось слово «усвояемый» и почему оно находит такую мощную поддержку в виде множества словарей? Всё дело в том, что глагол «усваивать» – относительно молодой, ещё лет сто назад он звучал как «усвоивать», а до того и вовсе – «усвоять». Это-то и объясняет происхождение нашего слова.
>
> Мы столкнулись с удивительным явлением в русском языке, когда глагол устаревает, а образованное от него причастие сохраняет всю свою силу и по-прежнему находит место в лексиконе современного человека. Объяснение этому я вижу в большей дружественности старого слова к языку как инструменту общения. Выговорить «усвояемый» не в пример проще и быстрее, чем «усваиваемый».
>
> Эксперты сайта spravka.gramota.ru полагают, что между этими словами существует разница в значениях. «Усвояемый», по их мнению, употребляется как термин, то есть в научном или официальном контексте, а слово «усваиваемый» – общеупотребительное, то есть чаще используется в обычной речи людей. Как бы то ни было, ясно одно: слово «усвояемый» существовало, существует, и в его правильности не стоит сомневаться ни на йоту.
>
> Ежи Лисовский

Answer (score 0):

Правильно **усвояемый** (высокоусвояемый).
Словари фиксируют именно этот вариант.
Вот здесь можно почитать небольшое рассуждение на эту тему: http://newslab.ru/article/180394

P. S. Здесь уже был такой вопрос, к тому обсуждению тоже можно обратиться: ["Усвояемый" или "усваиваемый"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Ставить вопрос о том, которое из слов _усвояемый/усваиваемый_ правильно (как в вопросе по ссылке), нельзя - оба слова существуют, важно лишь, в каком смысле их употребляют. Пример употребления в книге по психологии слова "усваиваемый": "... **усваиваемый** материал применяется в новых условиях...".

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=-weHCwAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PT216&img=1&zoom=3&ots=vLrWAXXu97&sig=ACfU3U29sPYBwF0TqRJ6OseHmcMXOcAClA&w=1280 P.S. Это далеко не единственная книга.